# Tmux colors lost

Tags: linux, tmux, colors

I've got two very similar Linux installations (Manjaro). On one of them the basic output is colored out of the box (no `~/.tmux.conf` yet). On another it's black an white. Adding

`~/.tmux.conf`:

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

makes no difference. Different console applications make no difference, too. What should I check?

Comment: On the one with b&w display, what does `echo $TERM` print before you start `tmux`?

Comment: It's `xterm-256color` on *both* boxes (colored display; b&w display).

Comment: Could there be alias or shell function involved? What's the output of `type tmux`?

Comment: `tmux is hashed (/usr/bin/tmux)` on both boxes.

Comment: try `TERM=xterm-color tmux`

Comment: Does not make any difference, unfortunately.